# Maui android. Either set MainPage or override CreateWindows

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, prism, maui

In maui android app, when app was moved to back it occassionally invokes Destroy and bringing app back to front, throws an exeption:

> Either set MainPage or override CreateWindows.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); <- throws here
 }
```

i tried to override code in App class:

```
 protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
 {
    return base.CreateWindow(activationState); <- throws here
 }
```

> System.NotImplementedException: 'Either set MainPage or override
> CreateWindow.'

also tried to restore previously successfully loaded window:

```
 private Window _window = null;

protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    if (MainPage == null && _window != null)
    {
        return _window;
    }

    return _window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
}
```

but app stays unresponsive after it.
Tried to use in AndroidManifest.xml options:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:killAfterRestore="false" android:noHistory="false" android:excludeFromRecents="false" android:persistent="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

none of that had a way to prevent from destroying app.
Part of my StartupClass:

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    MauiAppBuilder builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

    builder.UsePrismApp<App>(prism =>
    {
        prism.RegisterTypes(containerRegistry =>
        {
            //list of pages
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            ....
        })
        .OnAppStart(async (containerProvider, navigationService) =>
        {
            var navService = containerProvider.Resolve<INavigationService>();
            await navService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MyPage));
        });
```

here i use prism over maui.
So is there any way to prevent app from destroying or to successfully restore app state on recreate?

Answer (score 1):

> Maui android. Either set MainPage or override CreateWindows

About override CreateWindows, you can try to use following code:

```cs
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    if (this.MainPage == null)
    {
        this.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    return base.CreateWindow(activationState);
}
```

For more info you can refer to this issue: [[Android] App crashes when start from background](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4169). Wish it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this was not my case, the issue in my case seems to be in prism...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem myself lately. I'm using Shiny.Framework. But even the sample provided by Shiny.Framework throws the exception.

I googled some more, [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4169#issuecomment-1041257117) from maui repo shows me maybe this is an emulator problem. So I created a new emulator using the latest Android 33 image, and the problem went away.

I currently find that the default iamge comes with VS 2022, which is Android 29, will always throw the exception. I tried, it seems that images above android v31 works fine.

And PS:

The exception I have also had this message:

> (Sample) ChildIndex <= -1, Parent: App Child: PrismWindow

So I think it has something to do with Prism. But I'm no expert on Prism or Shiny, so I can't dig any deeper. Hoper some one can solve this mystery.

Comment: cant remember, but guess i just updated prism libs and this issue disappeared...

Comment: I got this error again lately after updating some nugets. I found that it's because I'm using a TabPage as my start page, and in this TagPage there's 3 sub pages. There's a error in one of the sub page viewmodel's constructor(it's december now and I add 1 to the month), after fix the viewmodel, everything runs smoothly. So defnititly check your viewmodels, it's probably minor errors in the code. I guess this is the downside of using IOC, error got burried too deep.